# Find ssh credentials from outgoing connection out a unix program

Tags: ssh, unix, decompile

I have a compiled UNIX program (written in C++) that makes a SSH connection to an IP address. I need to extract the hardcoded credentials. I have tried decompiling but with no success. I was wondering if I can somehow intercept the connection and figure out the credentials. Please help.

Comment: The question isn't really specific enough about the situation, like how is it making the connection+what auth type/SSH version? Decrypting SSH connections is basically not possible unless the shared secret (from the Diffie-Hellman key exchange) is extracted from the SSH server or client. If the program is it's own SSH client, there's not much you can do besides working through the decompiled info. If it's launching something external like `/bin/ssh`, you could trick it into sending creds to your own binary instead for example

Comment: What if when the program is running, take a memory dump and try extract the creds that way?

Comment: you will not be able to extract credentials from an SSH connection setup using a packet sniffer or related network monitoring tool. credentials exchange happens after a secure circuit has been created, and good luck gleaning useful information from that. the first thing I'd do is inspect the strings in the compiled binary (in windows I'd use strings.exe; I've done this to locate connection string connections for databases) but that will only work if the binary is not obfuscated. Memory extraction is theoretically possible, but you would have to be in a position to find the right addresses.